# Web service boleto registrado Santander

Tags: php, web-service

Estou implementando o método de registro de boleto do Santander via web service com PHP para um cliente. Já foi adquirido o certificado digital e instalado no servidor do sistema do cliente e também já instalado no banco Santander.

1. Em minha máquina eu importei o certificado no navegador e já consigo ter acesso a url de obtenção do ticket de segurança.

   https://ymbdlb.santander.com.br/dl-ticket-services/TicketEndpointService
2. O problema acontece quando tento consumir o web service com o SOAP. Nele eu informo a url do ticket e as opções contendo o caminho de onde está o arquivo .pem e a senha para acesso.

   ```
   try {
         $options = array('keep_alive' => false,
                          'trace' => true,
                          'local_cert' => 'https://(caminho).pem',
                          'passphrase' => '(senha)',
                          'cache_ws' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
                         );
         $cliTicket = new SoapClient("https://ymbdlb.santander.com.br/dl-ticket-services/TicketEndpointService/TicketEndpointService.wsdl", $options);
         echo "CHAMANDO O DLB TICKET!!";

         $xmlCreate = getTicketXml();
         $cResponse = $cliTicket->create($xmlCreate);

         print_r($cResponse);
   } catch(SoapFault $e) {
         echo "EXCEÇÂO DO SOAP";
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($e);
         echo "</pre>";
   }
   ```
3. Após executar esse código me é retornado uma exceção com a seguinte mensagem:

   ```
   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ymbdlb.santander.com.br/dl-ticket-services/TicketEndpointService/TicketEndpointService.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://ymbdlb.santander.com.br/dl-ticket-services/TicketEndpointService/TicketEndpointService.wsdl"
   ```

Alguém saberia me informar por qual motivo esse erro acontece ?

Comment: Veja se isto tem relação https://stackoverflow.com/a/28611495/1518921

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tentei usar as soluções do link que você passou e nenhuma deu certo

Comment: @AbnerFerreiradeAndrade Preciso implementar o registro online de boletos do Santander para o meu site, hospedado em um servidor de hospedagem linux compartilhado. A solução que vc criou é opensource?

Comment: @WarmBooter Não. Mas me foi enviado um exemplo de uso. Eu coloquei no github, acessa esse [link](https://github.com/abner071/abner/blob/master/exemplo_santander.php) e ve se te ajuda.

Comment: @AbnerFerreiradeAndrade Valeu, vai ajudar sim!

Comment: @AbnerFerreiradeAndrade Estou tendo o mesmo erro que vc tinha, com a diferença que meu servidor é Linux, e estou usando um certificado emitido pelo cPanel (enviei o CRT dele para o banco e foi aceito lá). Detalhe: o cPanel não tem passphrase no certificado, então estou omitindo esse parametro no array de opções. No local_cert, já tentei passar o path completo local, path relativo, etc e nada resolveu. Tem idéia do que possa ser?

Comment: @WarmBooter Desculpe a demora. Então você vai ter que gerar o certificado .pfx a partir do .crt que você tem com o programa OPENSSL. Depois de gerado importe o .pfx no navegador e exporte marcando a opção de exportar chave privada e a cadeia de certificação (também pedirá uma senha dai você informa uma que desejar). Após exportado terá que converter esse .pfx exportado para .pem com o mesmo programa OPENSSL.
Esse certificado .pem terá senha que você informou ao gerar e é ele que deverá ser informado no local_cert (caminho local a partir do arquivo de código), e no passphrase a senha usada.

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido.

O problema estava no valor da chave `local_cert` do array `$options`. Eu estava passando a url online para acessar o certificado no servidor, mas deveria ter passado apenas o local em que ele está no projeto. Ex: `cert/certificado.pem`